# Can't connect to Server.app local sites

Tags: safari, server.app, high-sierra

My development server is Server.app. After having to reinstall macOS in recovery mode, browsers can no longer connect to my local sites. I can't select the text of the error that Safari gves so here's a screenshot...
[image: Safari Can't Connect to the Server]

Other browsers give errors of the same substance.

Update: Looking elsewhere I found mention of Stealth Mode. On checking I found that was switched on during the reinstall. Turning it off now allows me to ping 127.0.0.1 & my local host names in Terminal, but I still can't reach my local hosts in a browser.

The Server.app webserver is on, & all my sites are still there. I've checked the configuration of the ones that matter most right now & they're still correct. My hosts file is still as it should be.

Update 2: Expanding as a result of answer by Tom E, what I get when running the command suggested is...

```
Europa:~ pedro$ host volhq.mmf.yii.dev
volhq.mmf.yii.dev has address 127.0.53.53
volhq.mmf.yii.dev mail is handled by 10 your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.dev.
```

I have always used a `hosts` file rather than DNS, taking the former to be simpler & sufficient for my needs, & that has worked until now. However if setting up a DNS is the medicine, I shall take it.

Update 3: I think the question now becomes, how do I get the IP address on my host names from `127.0.53.53` back to `127.0.0.1`? For more than 10 years I have used a `hosts` file with entries like `127.0.0.1 volhq.mmf.yii.dev` & it has worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stealth Mode is a feature of the built-in firewall. If enabled, it simply keeps the firewall from responding to ”ICMP echo requests“ (aka Pings). It doesn’t keep browsers from connecting to a web server.

In your case, the reason could be a problem with your DNS configuration. Please check both the client’s and the server’s DNS setup. Try to resolve volhq.mmf.yii.dev from the client’s command line:

```
host volhq.mmf.yii.dev
```

and see what reply the command gives you. Get back here if you don’t receive an error…

Comment: This is most helpful. I've put the result in an edit to the question.

Comment: Ok, there’s the problem. Any IP address starting with `127.0` refers to `localhost`. This does not make sense to any hosts except to your server itself. I’m afraid you’ll have to go through the process of setting up a clean DNS service on the server and make the clients look it up. You don’t need a lot more than an A record mapping `volhq.mmf.yii.dev` to your server’s _real_ IP address. The server.app calls it a “Computer record.”

Comment: The `127.0.53.53` bit continued to bug me. Eventually I came across this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662590/domain-foo-bar-points-127-0-53-53-why/25665936 from which I take that `.dev` is now a TLD & I (along with many other developers) need to start using something else instead.

Comment: You could still make your own _internal_ domain name point to whatever IP address you want—as long as you do not need to reach any of your network components from outside.